# Merel's theorem on uniform bound for torsion of all elliptic curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, cryptography, iwasawa-theory

I am reading Silverman's book on Arithmetic of elliptic curves. There he mentions a theorem of Merel (Thm 7.5.1) which reads like this.

Thm: For every integer $d \geq 1$, there is a constant $N(d)$ such that for all number fields $K/\mathbb{Q}$ of degree at most $d$ and all elliptic curves $E/K$, $$|E_{tors}(K)| \leq N(d).$$

This sounds like a very strong statement. Has there been generalizations of this statement for modular forms or Hilbert modular forms?

What are some applications of this theorem? Silverman doesn't seem to give many applications. Please list them if you know any.

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of generalisation for modular forms do you expect? What does a torsion point on a elliptic curve correspond to in the world of modular forms?

Comment: @Daniel. I was wondering if this theorem has an implication for the associated (family of) Galois representations from where we might be able to guess the appropriate generalization for modular forms.

Comment: @Daniel Loughran, translating the above statement when $K=\mathbb{Q}$, it means that $X_1(N)$ has no non-cuspidal rational points for large $N$. In fact, it is this equivalent formulation that was proved by Mazur. The proof of Kamienny for $d=2$ is performed by looking at the symmetric square of $X_0(N)$, and the modular curves $X_1(M,N)$. In general, Merel looks at the symmetric d-th power of the modular curve, and takes certain quotients. It is possible that this could also be approached by considering Hilbert modular surfaces, but by definition they classify different objects.

Comment: @Assaferen: Yes I'm aware how Merel's theorem relates to rational points on modular curves. But this does not seem to help with the OP's question which asks for a "generalizations of this statement for modular forms".